# Reading runtime values using AvroIO class

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I need to read an AVRO file in Apache Beam using AvroIO by passing the schema and filepath dynamically. Is there any way we can pass a ValueProvider or a side input or anything else to AvroIO.read.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> records =p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(dynamicallyProvidedSchema)
       .from(dynamicallyProvidedFilePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

`AvroIO.read().from()` can take a `ValueProvider`. For dynamically provided schema, Beam 2.2 (release is currently in progress) includes `AvroIO.parseGenericRecords()` that lets you avoid specifying a schema altogether, you just have to specify a function from `GenericRecord` to your custom type.